# Do beginner tenors ussually start doing exercices in some kind of mezza voce or full voice?

Tags: voice

Do beginner tenors ussually start doing exercices in some kind of mezza voce or full voice?
Some say that tenors do not begin learning to sing well by using full voice immediately. 
Some say that full voice (con la fronte?) takes time to learn. You cannot start with that I am being told.
Some people do not even talk about this. I guesd they think it us very natural for a beginner not to use his full voice yet.

Comment: Surely it's going to depend on an individual's actual range. Some encompass way more than 'tenor'. And no-one will push too hard at either end of that range, with any sense.

Comment: So mezzo voce is a thing used when training head voice? It is not used when singing let say around F#3-C3?

Comment: It seems that mezza voce is simply singing not too loudly, or quietly. Can't think why beginners would be expected to sing loudly. Doesn't appear t have anything to do with any particular range of notes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly healthy for beginning tenors to even think about "full" vs. "mezza voce." Young singers are better off taking the bel canto approach, which simply encourages healthy, natural vocal production backed by technically correct breathing. Without this fundamental approach full and mezza voce singing will be incorrect.

Comment: "which simply encourages healthy, natural vocal production backed by technically correct breathing"  This is 100% correct.  You've got to get the basics down pat first.  You're asking which race track to drive without yet knowing how to steer the car.